# Does the Distributive Property of Multiplication Over Addition apply to Absolutely Convergent Infinite Sums

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Does the Distributive Property of Multiplication Over Addition apply to Absolutely Convergent Infinite Sums

For example, is it true that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (k\cdot a_n) = k\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)$?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: It applies to limits and convergent infinite sums are limits.

Comment: The only issue is when $k=0$ and that is not a problem if the right-hand side is absolutely convergent